# What's special about the Dropbox Photos folder?

Tags: dropbox

Is there anything special about the Photos folder in Dropbox? As far as I can see it behaves exactly the same as any other non public folder, yet [Dropbox seems to suggest](https://www.dropbox.com/help/179/en) there's something different about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photos folder is the old way of sharing photos with Dropbox.  Basically, the idea was you could go to [www.dropbox.com/photos_folder](http://www.dropbox.com/photos_folder) and see & share nice photo galleries.  The simple idea was that each folder within the photos folder was automatically mapped to a gallery.

This feature has been deprecated, and probably won't be around much longer (i.e. the photos folder will be treated just like any other regular folder).  Instead, you should use the photos tab ([www.dropbox.com/photos](http://www.dropbox.com/photos)), which shows all the photos in your Dropbox, no matter which folder they are in.  Also, sharing is now not restricted to being everything in a particular folder - you can share any set of pictures you want from the photos tab, without having to worry about where they are in your Dropbox (This also means that if you want to share two overlapping sets of photos with different people, there is no need to duplicate the common images).  It's still possible to share any folder with anyone - just use the "get link" feature (which works for all filetypes, not just images) - and if that folder is full of images, the resulting page is a photo gallery (with the new & better design).

Hopes this helps clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Photos folder in Dropbox you can create public photo galleries. Just create a subfolder and name it as you would want to name a photo album, and put your photos inside this.

If you right click on this folder, you can get the link and share it with your friends. Whenever you want your photos to not be public, just remove them from the Photos folder.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wg1zq82e9t2fp8q/OFDWuVc9pK) is a sample photo album from my Dropbox

You can read more about Dropbox Photos folder [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/18/en).

Comment: How's that different from any other folder?

Comment: @stovroz other folders don't reate image galleries.

Comment: @Sathya - Yes they do.

Comment: @stovroz Got an example (or, evidence)? Screenshots?

Comment: Yeah, @stovroz is right. Even other folders with images create galleries. I just tried it. Well, they must have changed it recently, because earlier, other folders did not create galleries. So I guess now the Photos folder is just a default folder present in Dropbox to keep all your photos at one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a smart phone or tablet (iPhone, iPad, or Android) and the DropBox app installed on it, the most recent version of DropBox will sync the photos from that device to the Photos folder. This is a new feature in the latest version of the app and must be explicitly allowed.

Comment: Nope. It actually creates a new folder called Camera Uploads.

Comment: That's correct. So, my PHOTOS "folder" is always empty...